# Settling slider steps and default min and max values

Tags: matlab, slider, matlab-guide

I am trying to set min and max values of my slider when it creates.

```
function slider2_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to slider2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called
% Hint: slider controls usually have a light gray background.
if isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor',[.9 .9 .9]);
end
set(hObject, 'Max', 10, 'Min', 1);
```

but when the GUI opens, it throws and error and slider disappears

```
Warning: slider control can not have a Value outside of Min/Max range
Control will not be rendered until all of its parameter values are valid 
> In openfig at 135
  In gui_mainfcn>local_openfig at 286
  In gui_mainfcn at 234
  In gui at 44 
Warning: slider control can not have a Value outside of Min/Max range
Control will not be rendered until all of its parameter values are valid 
Warning: slider control can not have a Value outside of Min/Max range
Control will not be rendered until all of its parameter values are valid
```

And i am trying to set the slider steps as 1. even when it is dragged or when the increase/decrease button is used.

```
function slider2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to slider2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'Value') returns position of slider
%        get(hObject,'Min') and get(hObject,'Max') to determine range of slider

    set(handles.slider2, 'SliderStep' , [1/9,1/9] );
sliderValue = get(handles.slider2,'Value');
 set(handles.edit2,'String',sliderValue)
```

I have chosed 1/9 because, for unit steps i need to choose `maxvalue-minvalue`

Any leads on where i am going wrong will be helpful

Answer (score 2):

You will want to specify the `Value` in your `CreateFcn` as well because by default, the value will be `0` which is outside of your `Min`/`Max` range which will cause the `uicontrol` to not be rendered. Also, I would recommend setting the `SliderStep` from within the `CreateFcn` as well

```
function slider2_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    if isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
        set(hObject,'BackgroundColor',[.9 .9 .9]);
    end

    set(hObject, 'Max', 10, 'Min', 1, 'Value', 1, 'SliderStep', [1/9 1/9]);
```

Also if you want to force the slider value to always be an integer (even when dragged), you can round the `Value` property inside of the slider's callback

```
function slider2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    value = round(get(handles.slider2, 'Value'));
    set(handles.slider2, 'Value', value);

    % Do whatever you need to do in this callback
end
```